# Authenticate on cleos?

Tags: cleos

I just finished installing `cleos` and have been able to query my account information from the chain.

```
cleos -u http://nodes.get-scatter.com:80 get account hezdenzvg4ge
```

For actions that require authentication like creating an account or exchanging funds, I assume I have to enter my private key somewhere to enable those.

Is there a login command for authenticating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use `keosd` for that. It's the EOSIO default wallet. It works like a server on your computer, so after you run `keosd` you can access it by running `cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8900` from any other terminal window.

I suggest you create an alias using the above command, let's say you named it `cleosw`

Usually to create and/or unlock you will do:

```
cleosw wallet create # write down the password
cleosw wallet unlock # you will need it when the wallet session times out
cleosw wallet import YOUR_PK
```

Now after you have your wallet unlocked you can just run your commands:

```
cleosw push action TRANSACTION THAT YOU WANT TO SIGN
cleosw set contract ....
cleosw system newaccount ....
```

That's it, good luck!